# PHP PDO adding to database will not work? [calendar]

Tags: php, pdo, calendar

I found a calendar script anyways, Like the rest of my files I want them to run off one single config.php file. Every single script so far does, although I found a calendar script that is coded in PHP PDO the same language im coding the rest in although I Try and include config.php although for some reason it will not work.

**Original code of the script: [Which worked]**

```
<?php
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $start = $_POST['start'];
    $end = $_POST['end'];

try {
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database2', 'root', 'mypassword');
} catch(Exception $e) {
exit('Unable to connect to database.');
}
     // update the records
    $sql = "UPDATE evenement SET title=?, start=?, end=? WHERE id=?";
    $q = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $q->execu

te(array($title,$start,$end,$id));
    ?>
```

**My edit of the script:**

```
<?php
include "../inc/config.php";
$id = $_POST['id'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$start = $_POST['start'];
$end = $_POST['end'];

 // update the records
$sql = "UPDATE evenement SET title=?, start=?, end=? WHERE id=?";
$q = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($title,$start,$end,$id));
?>
```

**Config.php**

```
<?php
$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = 'mypassword';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=database2", $username, $password);
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please elaborate. What do you mean with _will not work_? Does it throw any error?

Comment: @Bjoern No error, but when going to Developer tools networking on google chrome I did find this: http://prntscr.com/2d34k1

Comment: What does your error log saying when the code was executed? Is the include path correct (maybe you're not including the file)?

Comment: I get nothing when its executed. And yes the include path is correct.

Comment: Have you tried verifying if the POST data is valid?

Comment: @Mihai Got it working and its saying its successfully been .. executed. Although it does not appear in my database..

Comment: @Lolmewn Got it working and its saying its successfully been .. executed. Although it does not appear in my database..